# Question about nested interval property.

Tags: real-analysis

One corollary that we have from Nested interval property is that if we have that the intervals $I_n = [a_n,b_n]$, then we have that $s \in \bigcap I_n$. Moreover, we have that $\lim \ a_n = s = \lim \ b_n$. I don't understand how do we get $\lim \ a_n = s = \lim \ b_n$ ? Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. We *don't* have$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n=s=\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}b_b.\tag{1}$$Suppose that each $a_n$ is $0$ and that each $b_n$ is one. Then the intersection of all intervals is $[0,1]$. Take any $s\in[0,1]$. Then $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n=s$ if and only if $s=0$ and $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}b_n=s$ if and only if $s=1$. In particular, we *never* have $(1)$ (I mean, in this example). The only case we have $(1)$ for every $s$ is when $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n=\{s\}$.